# Create db schema

Tags: database, database-design, schema, database-schema

Consider a scenario where electronics is a main category and TV, fridge etc. are the sub categories, how you will a create db schema (table structure) for it using single table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a nullable column that reference the identity column of itself.

Eg: 
CategoryID (primary key) NOT NULL
CategoryName NOT NULL
ParentCategoryID NULL reference CategoryID

Querying those type of hierarchical table is sometimes tricky, however you can create an unlimited levels of subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

Use ENUM

```
CREATE TABLE electronics (
    ...
    category ENUM("TV", "fridge", "etc"),
    ...
);
```

and if you need a multiple depth for categories:

```
CREATE TABLE electronics (
    ...
    category ENUM("TV", "fridge", "etc"),
    parent_category ENUM("TV", "fridge", "etc"),
    ...
);
```